# Maximum packet size for radius

Tags: authentication, packet, radius

Does RADIUS have a maximum packet size? One of my applications will require a signed biometric image to be sent for authentication purposes and I am unsure of whether radius will be able to handle it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can pass this information in the authenticator section wich is 16 octets (65k) long.

Comment: 16 octets is a lot less than 65k! Plus the authenticator is strictly defined by the radius protocol and can't be used for arbitrary data.

Comment: For future lookup - request authenticator should be random, unforgeable bitstring and response authenticator is basically a signature. Also it is 128 bits, which seems too small for "image". If this is not in fact image, but some signature, generated by the image, it may work, but it is good practice not to make changes in the protocol to the extend that requires modifications of both client and server. Normally you would have your own server, integrated with external authentication service that can implement whatever it wants.

Answer (score 6):

According to RFC 2865 that details the RADIUS protocol, although the Radius packet length field is 2 octets long, the maximum packet size is restricted to 4096 bytes (someone else may be able to clarify the reason for this). The length field per attribute is 1 octet and therefore attributes are limited to 255 bytes.

Comment: RFC 6929 defines 'Long' attributes which are fragmented into 253 byte chunks (length field includes attribute and length field in length).  So in this case and attribute can be as long as the packet.

Answer (score 4):

RFC7499 allows for large packets based on fragment reassembly, that is concatenating the contents of multiple RADIUS packets.

and states the rationale for the original limit as being:

> to avoid UDP
>      fragmentation as much as possible.  Back then, a size of 4096 bytes
>      seemed large enough for any purpose.  Now, new scenarios are emerging
>      that require the exchange of authorization information exceeding this
>      4096-byte limit.

The new limit isn't absolute. RFC7499 suggests that 25 roundtrips should be the maximum, and that packets should be limited to the network PMTU.